# How to get the value of an input component in the same datatable row as the button?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a datatable where the rows are dynamic and each row contain a `selectOneMenu`. If I have a button on each row and I want to get the selected item on the `selectOneMenu`, what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the collection behind datatable's `value` in a [`DataModel<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html).

```
private List<Item> items;
private DataModel<Item> model;  // +getter

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.items = loadItSomehow();
    this.model = new ListDataModel<Item>(items);
}
```

*(the `Item` in this example is just the javabean class representing every row, e.g. `Person`, `Product`, etc)*

Bind it to the datatable's `value` instead.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.model}" var="item">
```

If the dropdown is bound to a property of `Item` and the button to a method of the same bean ...

```
<h:column>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{item.value}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.values}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:column>
```

... then you can grab the current item by [`DataModel#getRowData()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html#getRowData%28%29) and corrspondingly also the selected value in action method as follows:

```
public void submit() {
    Item item = model.getRowData();
    String value = item.getValue();
    // ...
}
```