# How to bind <rich:dataTable> to backing bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Is there any way to bind rich:dataTable to the bean? I can show the items in non binding rich:dataTable, but when I add binding attribute, whole dataTable dissappear.

**Part of code:**

```
<rich:dataTable 
  id="tableDetail"
  value="#{myBdeCheck.dataListBde}"
  binding="#{myBdeCheck.dataTable}"
  var="bdeItem">

  <rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Select" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myBdeCheck.selectedRow}"/>
  </rich:column>

  <rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="Shift" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{bdeItem.dayShift}"/>
  </rich:column>

  <f:facet name="footer">  
    <h:commandButton id="btnAdd" action="#{myBdeCheck.add}"/>
  </f:facet>
</rich:dataTable>
```

For JSF is working `private HtmlDataTable dataTable;`.

Is there something else for richfaces? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HtmlDataTable` is for `<h:dataTable>`, not `<rich:dataTable>`.

I'm not sure what component class `<rich:dataTable>` is using, but to findout that, you need to replace `HtmlDataTable` by `Object` and then in the setter print/debug the `dataTable.getClass()` so that you can learn which one it is.

By the way, what do you need the binding for? To get the selected row? You could also use `DataModel<E>` as datatable value instead. For an example check the following answers:

- [How to get the value of an input component in the same datatable row as the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345937/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-input-component-in-the-same-datatable-row-as-the-butto)
- [Recommended JSF 2.0 CRUD frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180400/recommended-jsf-2-0-crud-frameworks/3180885#3180885)

Comment: Thank you, you've suggested me DataModel before, but I hadn´t a time yet. This time I'll try it :)

Comment: I googled somewhat and it look like that you should be using `org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable` (or at least one of its subclasses) for `<rich:dataTable>`. Anyway, you can learn about the exact class by binding to `Object` and debugging the `getClass()` so that you can change it afterwards to the right one, as suggested in my answer.

Comment: Thank you BalusC, that's it. I've also found it, but it didn't work yesterday, but today it does:) Could you, in nutshell, tell me something about advantages of DataModel?

Comment: BalusC, I've tried the second link you've posted, but there is java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.model.ListDataModel. I've found only one solution, make the Model transient, but it is bullshit (bean.model value is empty). Don't you know where is the problem?

Comment: Ops, it's @viewScoped.. @requestScoped is enogh, it works >:)

Answer (score 5):

For [Richfaces 3.3](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_dataTable.html):

```
org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlDataTable
```

For [Richfaces 4](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.0.X/4.0.0.Final/Component_Reference/en-US/pdf/Component_Reference.pdf)

```
org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable
```

Comment: And that's the problem, this doesn't work in my project, therefore I'm asking again even you helped me with primefaces binding :]

Comment: @gaffcz: Are you sure you included the correct component and not eh standard jsf HtmlDataTable class?

Comment: Is that component present in RF 4.0? OP is probably using RF 4.0.